# Let users choose if they want an Identicon, Monsterid or Wavatar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-picture

It would be nice if we can choose if we want our gravatar to be an identicon, monsterid or wavatar instead of only the boring identicon.

This should be a preference in the pref tab on the profile page.

I think it would be a nice feature.

Comment: Description: http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/04/22/identicons-monsterids-and-wavatars-oh-my/

Answer (score 3):

You can already create any picture you like and use it with Gravatar. I don't see the point of having multiple default picture services.

Comment: While I agree, identicon, monsterid, and wavatar are all options offered by Gravatar if the user hasn't specified an image.

Comment: I see. Still, it seems like if you're going to go to the trouble of configuring a particular default image service on Gravatar, you might as well create your own and use that.

Answer (score 3):

I find the other auto-generated avatar types *incredibly* ugly.

Comment: I don't know, I think the monsterid flavor might be particularly appropriate for, say, meta.stackoverflow.com.